# Remove TOC removes pagestyling from other pages

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I don't want a toc in my document so I have removed by setting the command to empty like this:

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{}
```

This removes the toc perfectly but it also seems to mess with my page styling. I have defined some page styles which adds pagenumbers, logos etc to the footer but these only appears on pages where a new chapter starts. I am 99% sure that the command above that removes the toc is the reason for the missing page styles. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to remove the toc that doesn't

Comment: If you do not want automatically generated table of contents in your document, simply do not put ``\tableofcontents`` command in your document. There is no need to redefine this command; just don't use it in document at all.

Comment: If for some reason you absolutely have to redefine this command and let's say your page style with logos, page numbers etc. in the footer is called ``yourpagestyle``, you can do this: ``\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{yourpagestyle}}``

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that I use Sphinx to generate my Latex document, and \tableofcontent is automatically added to the document.

Comment: I am not familiar with Sphinx, but in this case my second comment should help.

Comment: I tried what you suggested in your second comment, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: as I understand, setting sphinx toctree to `hidden` surpresses the toc

Comment: Yes, but clearly I am doing it wrong with Sphinx. But setting pagestyle instead of thispagestyle in Rafals previous suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ``pagestyle`` sets style for this and each subsequent page. Since I wasn't sure you wanted to change that globally, I suggested ``thispagestyle`` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change style for TOC page and all subsequent pages (that is: until same command with different style is issued), use :

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\pagestyle{yourcustompagestyle}}
```

If you want to change style only for TOC page, use:

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{yourcustompagestyle}}
```